# Minimal Safari Address Bar and Navigation bar don't hide on iOS when scroll with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios

In a long web page in Safari iOS, when the user scrolls by itself, the address bar goes to minimal size and the navigation bar at bottom hides.

But, if I use Javascript to scroll to a specific part of the page, the address and navigation bar still.

It's possible to have the same behavior with Javascript as when the user scrolls?